# How to query for Facebook events using java

Tags: java, facebook, events, graph, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a simple way to query for events created in Facebook using a Java interface.

e.g. `Fetch me all events happening in San Jose, CA during the course of 1 week from now`

e.g. `Fetch me all events categorized by music around San Jose, CA within a span of 5 miles radius`

e.g. `Fetch me all events happening in San Jose, CA sorted by number of participants` - interested in knowing events were large number of users participate.

I also found references to the following API available, but not sure which one to use. RestFB seems to be have more traffic compared to facebook-java-api.

```
http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/types/Event.html
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

It's a REST-like interface that they provide for accessing facebook.

Comment: None of the tools https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/ seem to list a Java only option. I would prefer to use an API interface to fetch objects.

Comment: The API is REST-like. You query it with a `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: Appreciate, if you can provide us with a sample API demonstration.